# pass white space between string time and int data type in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have four variables:-

```
measure = 'domain.bandwidth' (string type)
time = datetime.datetime.now() (datetime type)
players_count = 50 (int type)
bandwidth = 3672782 (int type)
```

I am using teh below code to get the desired output :-

```
import datetime

measure = 'domain.bandwidth'
time = datetime.datetime.now()
players_count = 50
bandwidth = 3672782

print('%s,time=%s,players_count=%s,bandwidth=%s'
        % (measure, time.strftime('%Y-%M-%d %H:%I:%S.%f'), players_count, bandwidth))
```

Ouput :- `domain.bandwidth,time=2020-09-23T16:51:35Z,last_minute_total_players=227,last_minute_outgoing_bandwidth_bytes=1775874`

I want the output as:-

```
domain.bandwidth time=2020-09-23T16:51:35Z,last_minute_total_players=227,last_minute_outgoing_bandwidth_bytes=1775874
```

Which is a space between `domain.bandwidth` and `time` and not a comma.

Comment: Do you understand what's going on in that `print` statement? You just replace that first comma with a space ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this want you want?

```
import datetime

measure = 'domain.bandwidth'
time = datetime.datetime.now()
players_count = 50
bandwidth = 3672782

print('%s time=%s,players_count=%s,bandwidth=%s'
        % (measure, time.strftime('%Y-%M-%d %H:%I:%S.%f'), players_count, bandwidth))
```

Output:

```
domain.bandwidth time=2020-59-23 18:06:12.007382,players_count=50,bandwidth=3672782
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
new_time = time.strftime('%Y-%M-%d %H:%I:%S.%f')
print(f"{measure} time={new_time}, last_minute_total_players={players_count}, last_minute_outgoing_bandwidth_bytes={bandwidth}")
```